# How to use a descreteMapper like on cytoscapeweb?

Tags: cytoscape.js

My nodes contain an attribute "classid". For every classid I would like to use a specific background-image.
How can I map data to a node-attribute, like it was possible on cytoscapeweb by using the descretemapper (http://cytoscapeweb.cytoscape.org/documentation/mappers#section/DiscreteMapper)?

Here my code from cytoscapeweb:

```
var iconMapper = {
        defaultValue: "icons/BMC_BASEELEMENT.png",
        discreteMapper: {
            attrName: "classid",
            entries: [
                { attrValue: "BMC_CHASSIS", value: "icons/BMC_CHASSIS.png" },
                { attrValue: "BMC_CLUSTER", value: "icons/BMC_CLUSTER.png" },
                { attrValue: "BMC_ACTIVITY", value: "icons/BMC_ACTIVITY.png" },
                (...)
                { attrValue: "BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM", value: "icons/BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM.png" }

            ]
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the data mapper:

e.g. "data(classid)"

http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#style/mappers

Comment: e.g. "path/to/img/data(classid).png"