# How to specify discrete mapper style in cytoscapejs?

Tags: css, json, cytoscape.js

I am specifying the cytoscape.js style via css (and converting to the JSON format using [this](https://github.com/aschriner/cytoscapejs-css-style)).  I am trying to use a discrete mapper for the style.  Similar to [How to use a descreteMapper like on cytoscapeweb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933384/how-to-use-a-descretemapper-like-on-cytoscapeweb) but I don't want to just pass through the data(blah) value, I want to set different values based on different data(blah) values.  Like this (which I based off what I found [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/wiki/Styleobject))

```
node { 
   color : {
        defaultValue: red,
        discreteMapper: {
            attr: n_phosphorylated,
            mapped: {
                true: blue
            }
    }};
}
```

I am getting `TypeError: element._private.style.color.value is undefined`.  Do I have the syntax wrong or is this not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer from this comment:
[How to create custom style mapping in cytoscape.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323792/how-to-create-custom-style-mapping-in-cytoscape-js?rq=1#comment26976283_18340521)

The correct way is to use selectors based on the data:

```
node[?n_phosphorylated] {
    color: blue;
}
```

Here the `?` operator means (roughly) n_phosphorylated=true.

Thanks Max